# Can mysql fields in greek language be displayed in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Creating a MySQL table with fields in the Greek language is not very smart. As a newbie I just found that out. Those fields cannot be displayed in crystal reports (CR for Visual Studio version 13.08). I have thousands lines of code so it will take me ages changing MySQL fields and then change all my queries. I am using C# through Visual Studio 2012.

I checked many solutions I have found online like changing font, changing regional settings of my pc or changing collation of my database and nothing has worked.

Those fields are displayed with question marks `??` and when I try to run the program I get this error message: `mysql(42s22) unknown column in 'Field List' Error 1054`

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this problem too recently and i actually tried all the above you mentioned, and the solution i found was:

1. go to your ODBC Data Source Adminstrator (access it from the 'set up ODBC data sources' )
2. on the USER Data Source choose your database and press configure,
3. and go down to Details and press it,
4. now you will see a 'Character Set' field, press it and choose 'greek'
5. save,exit and go to your visual studio project, and create a new crystal report
6. then choose to make a new connection(i did it again just to be sure that the configuration of my database was changed)
7. i used the new database to display my tables, and now you must not get the question marks!!! hooray!
8. use a font that supports greek characters, i used HellasArial, and greek were successfully displayed on my report.